# CS-Cart Change Page Title Display

Tags: seo, title, page-title, cs-cart

I have a cs-cart project which display page titles in a way I do not want (well, in a way the client does not like).

I want it to display: 
On Home Page: Company Name
On Other Pages: Comapny Name | Page Title (i.e. Company Name | About Us ), etc.

I have the following script:

```
    {strip}
<title>

{if $page_title && $controller != 'products' && $controller != 'categories'}
        {$page_title|escape:"html"}
{else}
        {foreach from=$breadcrumbs|array_reverse item=i name="bkt"}
                {if !$smarty.foreach.bkt.last}{if !$smarty.foreach.bkt.first} - {/if}{$i.title|unescape|strip_tags|escape:"html"}{/if}
        {/foreach}
        {if !$skip_page_title}{if $breadcrumbs|count > 1} - {/if}{$location_data.title|escape:"html"}{/if}
{/if}

</title>
{/strip}
```

How to update the script to display what I want? You help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:
1) Each location can has own titles:
For 3.x http://screencast.com/t/Le70K95A1W
For 4.x http://screencast.com/t/MJP76TwSbT

So you can define a different titles for different locations (Homepage, Cart page, etc)

2) Each objects (pages, products, categories) have personal SEO settings. For example, "pages": ttp://screencast.com/t/WqnNJBxyKO

For each page you can specify personal titles.